# Using sed to remove all console.log from javascript file

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm trying to remove all my `console.log`, `console.dir` etc. from my JS file before minifying it with YUI (**on osx**).

The regex I got for the console statements looks like this:

```
console.(log|debug|info|warn|error|assert|dir|dirxml|trace|group|groupEnd|time|timeEnd|profile|profileEnd|count)\((.*)\);?
```

and it works if I test it with the [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/).
But it won't work with `sed`.

What do I have to change to get this working?

```
sed 's/___???___//g' <$RESULT >$RESULT_STRIPPED
```

**update**

After getting the first answer I tried

```
sed 's/console.log(.*)\;//g' <test.js >result.js
```

and this works, but when I add an OR

```
sed 's/console.\(log\|dir\)(.*)\;//g' <test.js >result.js
```

it doesn't replace the "logs":

[image: terminal screenshot]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your original expression looks fine. You just need to pass the `-E` flag to `sed`, for **extended** regular expressions:

```
sed -E 's/console.(log|debug|info|...|count)\((.*)\);?//g'
```

The difference between these types of regular expressions is explained in `man re_format`.
To be honest I have never read that page, but instead simply tack on an `-E` when things don't work as expected. =)

Comment: Your my best friend now! ```console.(log|debug|info|count)\((.*)\);?``` in sublime safely cleaned 2k lines. no more ugly logs :-)

Answer (score 2):

You must escape `(` (for grouping) and `|` (for oring) in `sed`'s regex syntax. E.g.:

```
sed 's/console.\(log\|debug\|info\|warn\|error\|assert\|dir\|dirxml\|trace\|group\|groupEnd\|time\|timeEnd\|profile\|profileEnd\|count\)(.*);\?//g'
```

**UPDATE** example:

```
$ sed 's/console.\(log\|debug\|info\|warn\|error\|assert\|dir\|dirxml\|trace\|group\|groupEnd\|time\|timeEnd\|profile\|profileEnd\|count\)(.*);\?//g'
console.log # <- input line, not matches, no replacement printed on next line
console.log
console.log() # <- input line, matches, no printing

console.log(blabla); # <- input line, matches, no printing

console.log(blabla) # <- input line, matches, no printing

console.debug();  # <- input line, matches, no printing

console.debug(BAZINGA)  # <- input line, matches, no printing

DATA console.info(ditto); DATA2 # <- input line, matches, printing of expected data
DATA  DATA2
```

HTH

Comment: What you had tried as a second solution is searching for `console.` then any of `log` OR `dir` then a pair of `()` with our without any character within (e.g. `()` and `(((((()` are valid matches) then a `;`.

Comment: You should have had added that you are on OSX earlier... OSX sed != GNU sed. See the answer by Martin.

Comment: sorry, for that ... didn't know about the differences + added the osx part with the first update

Answer (score 1):

I also find the way to remove all the console.log ,
and i am trying to use python to do this,
but i find the Regex is not work for.
my writing like this:

> **var re=/^console.log(.*);?$/;**

but it will match the following string:

> **'console.log(23);alert(234dsf);'**

does it work? with the

> "s/console.(log|debug|info|...|count)((.*));?//g"

Answer (score 1):

I try this:

```
sed -E 's/console.(log|debug|info)( ?| +)\([^;]*\);//g'
```

See the test:
[Regex Tester](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=console.%28log%7Cdebug%7Cinfo%29%28%20?%7C%20%2b%29%5C%28%5B%5E;%5D%2a%5C%29;&input=var%20a=5%2btest%28%29;%0Aconsole.log%28agshdgahs%2bsdjkfahs%20sd%28%29%29;%0Aconsole.log%28%29;game%28%29;%0Adskjahfkjd%28%29;%0Aalert%28234dsf%29;console.log%28func%28%29%29;alert%28234dsf%29;%0Aconsole.log%28%29;%0Aconsole.log%20%20%20%20%28%29;%0Aconsole.log%20%28blabla%29;%20%0Aconsole.debug%28%29;%20%20%0ADATA%20console.info%28ditto%29;%20DATA2%20%28%29;%0ADATA%20%20DATA2;)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my implementation

```
for i in $(find ./dir -name "*.js")
do

sed -E 's/console\.(log|warn|error|assert..timeEnd)\((.*)\);?//g' $i > ${i}.copy && mv ${i}.copy $i

done
```

took the sed thing from github

Answer (score 0):

I was feeling lazy and hoping to find a script to copy & paste. Alas there wasn't one, so for the lazy like me, here is mine. It goes in a file named something like 'minify.sh' in the same directory as the files to minify. It will overwrite the original file and it needs to be executable.

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *.js
do
    sed -Ei 's/console.(log|debug|info)\((.*)\);?//g' $f
    yui-compressor $f -o $f
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd just like to add here that I was running into issues with namespaced console.logs such as window.console.log.  Also Tweenmax.js has some interesting uses of console.log in some parts such as

```
       window.console&&console.log(t)
```

So I used this

```
  sed -i.bak s/[^\&a-zA-Z0-9\.]console.log\(/\\/\\//g js/combined.js
```

The regex effectively says replace all console.logs that don't start with &, alphanumerics, and . with a '//' comment, which uglify later takes out.

Answer (score 0):

Rodrigocorsi's works with nested parentheses. I added a ? after the ; because yuicompressor was omitting some semicolons.

Answer (score 0):

It is probable that the reason this is not working is that you are not 'limiting'
the regex to not include a closing parenthesises (`)`) in the method parameters.

Try this regular expression:

```
console\.(log|trace|error)\(([^)]+)\);
```

Remember to include the rest of your method names in the capture group.