# debug and production versions of javascript

Tags: javascript, debugging

I have a js file that contains lots of debug statements. I am looking for a script or compiler that will skip these debug statements, and can provide a production version.

```
function init(){
  console.log('initing the lib');
  ...
  .. some code here ..
  ...
  console.log('init over');
}
```

I need to have a production version that has none of these console.log's. This will allow for writing a debug version that can be used to see where exactly the error is occuring.

Comment: what are "debug statements" exactly? can you explain with a few sample code?

Comment: Added an example for the debug code.

Comment: can't your IDE do a regexp replace of `/console\.log\(.*\)/`?

Comment: this will be manual. We need something that we can use for CI testing.

Comment: who said anything about manual, when [there exists automation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6595429/575527) - this might be on Mac, but surely there are similar tools in other platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [googles closure compile](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) can help you out?

If you're worried about the `console.log` (seems that's what you mean by 'debug statements'), it may be an idea to override it in production:

```
var isProduction = true; //or false
if (isProduction){
 window.console = {log: function(){return true;}};
}
```

Comment: Does it have something that lets you mark a section as debug code it should omit?

Comment: In the faq (http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/wiki/FAQ), this is stated: *Closure Compiler will remove code that isn't used or exported.*  
Maybe this is applicable: https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3?#removal

Comment: You will maybe want to mark this variable as constant: `/** @const */ var DEBUG = false;`