# How to remove console.log from js files using MVC.NET Bundle config file

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, minify

My current bundle config concatenates all the script files and minifies it and generates a single file.but is not removing the **console.log** lines from the js files,how to add configuration to remove **console.log()** lines from the files.my current config setting is

```
       bundles.Add(
            new Bundle(
                "~/Scripts/js-bundle",
                new IBundleTransform[] {new JsMinify() }).Include(
            "~/Scripts/script1.js",
            "~/Scripts/script2.js",
            "~/Scripts/script3.js"))
```

I tried adding LogRemoverTransform() but i am getting some error

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove JS logging calls in our prod build of our mvc3 web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889237/how-to-remove-js-logging-calls-in-our-prod-build-of-our-mvc3-web-app)

Comment: when i include LogRemoverTransform() i am getting call not found error

Comment: you need to implement `IBundleTransform` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18509506/search-and-replace-in-javascript-before-bundling

Comment: i have implemented IBundleTransform.  new jsMinify() and new BabelTransform() was working fine. when i added new LogRemoverTransform i am getting the error.

Comment: didn't see the update. What is the error?

Comment: @adiga pls find the update

Comment: if you have `LogRemoverTransform.cs` in your porject, then you should see the option to add the `namespace` for that class in "*Show Potential Fixes*" link on that error.

Comment: @adiga i dont know how the code should be for LogRemoverTransform.cs. can you pls give me sample how it should be

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create your own `Bundle Transformation`, by implementing `IBundleTransform`. You can use [this regex](https://www.regexpal.com/?fam=99218) ([borrowed from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6595429)) to get the instances of `console.log`, `console.info` etc and replace them with empty strings.

```
public class LogRemoverTransform : IBundleTransform
{
    public void Process(BundleContext context, BundleResponse response)
    {
        var compiled = string.Empty;
        var pattern = "console.(log|debug|info|warn|error|assert|dir|dirxml|trace|group|groupEnd|time|timeEnd|profile|profileEnd|count)\\((.*)\\);?";

        foreach (var file in response.Files)
        {
           // read text from js file, and replace the the matched parts with empty string
            compiled += Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(file.IncludedVirtualPath)), pattern, string.Empty);
        }

        response.Content = compiled;
        response.ContentType = "text/javascript";
    }
}
```

And then in your `BundleConfig`:

```
bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/Scripts/js-bundle",  new LogRemoverTransform(), new JsMinify())
                  .Include("~/Scripts/script1.js",
                           "~/Scripts/script2.js",
                           "~/Scripts/script3.js"));
```

If the `js` files are very big, use `StreamReader` instead of `File.ReadAllText()`.